# MATLAB - Adding a field to the begining of an existing struct

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct, concatenation

I have a 1x100000 struct in MATLAB. It occurs to me that I need to add a field to it, which is easy and fine.. however i can't seem to add the field to the beginning i.e. make the new field the first field.

my struct looks like this

```
DB(kk).StudyDate
DB(kk).StudyTime
DB(kk).PatientName
```

i wish to make it

```
DB(kk).PatientID  <---- new field
DB(kk).StudyDate
DB(kk).StudyTime
DB(kk).PatientName
```

and not

```
DB(kk).StudyDate
DB(kk).StudyTime
DB(kk).PatientName 
DB(kk).PatientID  <---- new field
```

this is more for aesthetics and presentation purposes than anything else as it won't really affect how the struct is used whether the new field is at the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`orderfields`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orderfields.html) function exists for this purpose:

```
%   Order based on permuting current field ordering
DB = struct('StudyDate','2015/04/27','StudyTime',now(),'PatientName','Baz Bar');
DB.PatientID = dec2hex(randi([1,2^32]));
DB = orderfields(DB,[4,1,2,3]);

%   Does the same with explicit fieldnames
DB = struct('StudyDate','2015/04/27','StudyTime',now(),'PatientName','Baz Bar');
DB.PatientID = dec2hex(randi([1,2^32]));
DB = orderfields(DB,{'PatientID','StudyDate','StudyTime','PatientName'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way (AFAIK) to do this is to make a brand new struct and copy all the fields into it in the order you would like them displayed.